# Kafka Windowing Streams Junk Data With Windowed Ktable Serdes

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, windowing

I am working on a Kafka Streaming Dashboard where I need count of daily data of last 24 hours

`stream.groupByKey()  .windowedBy(TimeWindows.of(Duration.ofHours(24)).grace(Duration.ofMinutes(5)))  .aggregate(() -> "0",(key, value, aggregate) -> value,Materialized.with(Serdes.String(), Serdes.String())).suppress(untilWindowCloses(unbounded())) .toStream().to("Test_windowing1");`

In Above code I am trying to view data with of past 24 hours with windowing but the output before streaming with windowing and after are

Before Windowing

Key: 2023010612
Value: {"Title":"HOURLY_COUNT","Count":"19967","Key":"2023010612"}

After Windowing

Key: 2023010612����
Value: {"Title":"HOURLY_COUNT","Count":"19967","Key":"2023010612"}

I want to delete the past 2 days data with windowing and have same result for the key after windowing as well

Thank you in Advance

Comment: `I want to delete the past 2 days data` -- Kafka topics are append only -- there is no delete operation. What are you trying to achieve? -- Note that the result key type after the aggregation is `Windowed<K>` -- thus you need to consume the result topic using  `TimeWindowedDeserializer` (or inject a `map()` step after `toStream()` to transform the key before writing into the result topic).

Comment: The deletion was expected to allocate the specific size for the application was done with RETENTION_BYTES_CONFIG and for the windowed serializer I had the deserialize the windowed data as you mentioned